# Customise email before sending

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am recoding a friend's artist/client booking system.  I have little experience in programming, enough understanding to hack my way through and google has been a great help!

I've spent the last 3 days reading and searching... Havn't found anything on that... Maybe I'not using the proper terms....

Here's what I want to do.
I use Google Script and google spreadsheet.  1 row contains all the information about a specific contract.

1. I want to be able to use a menu item to generate the contract (completed)
2. Open 2 browser window

   - one to display the Contract PDF file  ( completed )
   - one for a GMAIL New email

     - with the contract pdf attached  ( completed )
     - generated email body  from selected row in the spreadsheet( completed )
     - be able to customize the generated email text before
       sending it. Adding attachements...

This is what I'm stucked at.  I use

> MailApp.sendEmail('xxx@yyy.com', 'transfer email as pdf : body
>   & attachment', 'see attachment', {attachments:[body_to_send]});

It send's the email ok, with attachement and generated body and all... but no way to edit the email before sending...

Is that possible with google script?

Comment: Apps script has nothing to do with app engine.

Comment: @Saumier are you still working on this, did you find a solution?

Comment: Where are you willing to edit the mail?

Answer (score 0):

Explore the UiApp class in Google Apps Script. [UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app)

You could build a simple UI where the user can enter additional content and upload files, which can then be appended to the email before sending.

It doesn't look like Apps Script supports creating email drafts, which would also provide a way for you to edit emails before sending them.  (Sending an email to yourself with a fancy way to reference the ultimate recipient is another possibility using the native Gmail UI.)

Is this in the direction you were thinking?

Answer (score 0):

The last step of your process can be achieved using a Google Doc template in which you can add whatever you want to improve presentation. 
From there you get an html version of your doc and use it as a html body in your mail.
If you need more details about html import you'll find it easily on this forum and on the issue tracker.
You could also run this code from a document bound script in a sidebar which would be visually more convenient. (see my recent posts about mailmerge).